# Requests SSL connection timeout

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm using python requests to send http requests to www.fredmeyer.com

I can't even get past an initial get request to this domain. doing a simple `requests.get` results in the connection hanging and never timing out. i've verified i have access to this domain and am able to run the request on my local machine. can anyone replicate

Comment: The community can't really help you unless you show us the code that you've written, and how it's failing.

Comment: The code I've written is literally just `requests.get('https://www.fredmeyer.com')`

How it's failing is that it isn't failing. When I execute `python script.py` it just hangs forever.

Comment: maybe that website doesn't want anyone instead web browsers to connect. Try adding into `get()` function argument `headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'}`

Comment: This hangs too with curl but seems to work with a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site seems to have some filtering enabled to prohibit bots or similar. The following HTTP request works currently with the site:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.fredmeyer.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html
Accept-Encoding:
```

If the `Connection` header is removed or its value changed to `close` it will hang. If the (empty) `Accept-Encoding` header is missing it will also hang. If the `Accept` line is missing it will return `403 Forbidden`.

In order to access this site with requests the following currently works for me:

```
import requests
headers = { 'Accept':'text/html', 'Accept-Encoding': '', 'User-Agent': None }
resp = requests.get('https://www.fredmeyer.com', headers=headers)
print(resp.text)
```

Note that the heuristics used by the site to detect bots might change, so this might stop working in the future.

Comment: Thanks - the site uses akamai for load balancing/content delivery and also uses it for traffic filtering. Seems they're using a very aggressive model to filter traffic..