# Perl: HTTP::Tiny Connection Stalls, get() never returns

Tags: perl, https, timeout, blocking

I'm using perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.080 on fedora35 and trying to check for the status of a URL to determine the return code. My script runs fine until it comes across this particular URL with a PDF at sophos.com. The script just stalls and the get() or head() call with new() just never returns. I've also tried to set a timeout and it appears to be ignored.

```
use HTTP::Tiny;  
use Net::FTP::Tiny qw(ftp_get);
my $url = "https://news.sophos.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/CloudSnooper_report.pdf";
my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new(timeout => 2)->get($url);
print "status: $response->{status} $url\n";
```

The print is just never reached. Using wget manually succeeds, while trying to set the agent to something other than "HTTP/Tiny" fails.

```
my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new(agent => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36")->get($url);
```

This code is part of a larger script that I'm using to check a series of URLs from a buffer to determine whether they're 404s and should be removed, or are still working links.

I'm unsure what further info I can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you have for news.sophos.com redirects to some other URL at [www.sophos.com](http://www.sophos.com). The latter server is protected by Akamai CDN:

```
$ dig www.sophos.com
...
www.sophos.com.         169     IN      CNAME   www.sophos.com.edgekey.net.
www.sophos.com.edgekey.net. 469 IN      CNAME   e6203.b.akamaiedge.net.
e6203.b.akamaiedge.net. 300     IN      A       23.60.192.131
```

The bot protection of Akamai can show some weird behavior if the request is not a typical one send by the browser. This might be failing with status code 403 but also just hanging as you experience, i.e. [tarpitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarpit_(networking)) the client. See also [Requests SSL connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187280/requests-ssl-connection-timeout) or [Strange CURL issue with a particular website SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53810155/strange-curl-issue-with-a-particular-website-ssl-certificate). See also [Why does Akamai edge services sometime just not send any response, leaving the connection to timeout](https://myakamai.force.com/customers/s/question/0D54R00007GjCANSA3/why-does-akamai-edge-services-sometime-just-not-send-any-response-leaving-the-connection-to-timeout?language=en_US) which incidentally describes a similar problem you have with [www.sophos.com](http://www.sophos.com).

In this specific case simply adding an `Accept` header to the request worked for me:

```
my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new(default_headers => { Accept => '*/*' })->get($url);
```

Note that this workaround might no longer work in the future when Akamai adjusts its bot detection.

> I've also tried to set a timeout and it appears to be ignored.

This is a known issue, which is especially noticeable when TLS 1.3 is used - as is the case here. See [Sometimes, timeout can fail to fire #146](https://github.com/chansen/p5-http-tiny/issues/146).

Comment: Okay, the "Accept" header worked, but where did you learn of this? What does it do? How does it change the behavior whereas changing the user agent isn't sufficient?

Comment: @AlexRegan: *"where did you learn of this"* - experience and research :) You are not the first one to tackle this issue and I'm not first time dealing with this kind of problems. *"How does it change the behavior whereas changing the user agent isn't sufficient?"* - user-agent is an too obvious choice. The times were bots could just change it to bypass anti-bot protections is long over. Today's anti-bot protection is harder to bypass. The workaround I've shown might stop working when too much use it - then Akamai will update the protection.